# HTTPS for Shiny apps?

Tags: r, ssl, nginx, shiny, shiny-server

Any ideas how I can add HTTPS to Shiny apps?

I came across a few guides below but not sure whether they are reliable or not.

[Adding Authentication to Shiny Server in 4 Simple Steps](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-authentication-to-shiny-server/)

[ADD AUTHENTICATION TO SHINY SERVER WITH NGINX](https://www.datascienceriot.com/add-authentication-to-shiny-server-with-nginx/kris/)

[Shiny https: Securing Shiny Open Source with SSL](https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-https-securing-shiny-open-source-with-ssl/)

I probably should follow the one from r-bloggers because I have my Shiny server installed in Linode hosting servers.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I want to add https to my app's url, eg - currently I access my app via http://myshinyapp.org but I need https://myshinyapp.org as well.

Comment: Do you mean add User Auth? Your links suggest you want users to log in and be able to set permission levels server-side. I interpret HTTPS as adding an SSL certificate to the domain/server shiny-server is hosted on

Are you able to add an SSL certificate on the server side to your domains? What I mean is, I run on Linux cloud servers, and they are configured with SSL certs so that all sub domains are covered. So, for `https://website-a.com`, shiny-server is also SSL via `https://website-a.com/shiny/*`.

Comment: @CarlBoneri no, not user auth. I want to add https to my app's url, eg - currently I access my app via http://myshinyapp.org but I need https://myshinyapp.org as well.

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/ can get you there.

Comment: @CarlBoneri it has no guide on how to do it.

Comment: @CarlBoneri also, Linode is not in the list https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/web-hosting-who-support-lets-encrypt/6920

Comment: What you are looking for isn't an R or shiny solution. You need to install an SSL/TSL cert on your server for the domain. That's what makes a site secure, and then you configure your dns records accordingly.  And in response to your last comment... [Install Let’s Encrypt to Create SSL Certificates](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates)

Comment: @CarlBoneri thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this can't be done. From [the official docs published by RStudio](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html#custom-domains):

> shinyapps.io does not currently support secure URLs for custom domains. The URLs you define in the application settings are accessible only via the http protocol, not the https protocol.

So if you want to use your custom domain (e.g., `myshinyapp.org` instead of `myname.shinyapps.io/myshinyapp`), you have to use http, not https.